# railsのwebシステム内にpythonのスクリプトを共存させることは可能でしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, python

現在、WebサービスをRuby on Rails で開発しております。
※BtoB向けの社内ツール

しかし、以下の要因から、一部機能をpythonにて実装したいと考えております。

・webサイト内で高度な数値計算を行う際にrubyよりかはpythonの方が簡単にでき、かつ、pythonであれば、そのノウハウを持っている。

・協力していただいているメンバーがpython経験者でRuby未経験が複数名いる。

すべてをpythonでやるという選択肢も考えましたが、最終的にはメインをrailsでやり、一部pythonを組み込むという方針でやりたいと考えております。

そのような方法は可能なのでしょうか？

rails でいうところの link_to のようなヘルパーメソッドからpythonスクリプトを呼び出せるのかがよくわかりませんでした。
※link_toに限らずですが、ページ遷移や動的にpythonスクリプトが実行できるようであれば、そうしたいです。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 12):

いろいろやり方はあります。簡単な順に書きますと

1. `IO.popen`などのプロセス間通信を使ってRubyからPythonのプログラムを呼び出す
2. FlaskやDjangoなどで別のウェブを裏で立ち上げて、RoRからはリバースプロキシでアクセスする。
3. redisなどでタスクキューを作って、RoRからは計算タスクをジョブ番号と共にタスクキューに追加する。ジョブ番号をブラウザに通知する。Pythonはタスクが入る度に計算して、ジョブ番号をキーにして結果をDBに保存。ブラウザはジョブ番号でRoRに結果を問い合わせ。ステータスを表示
   (計算待ち、計算中、計算済み）。計算済みなら結果を表示。

3のやり方は、例えばPythonの計算が重たくて数分以上かかるときに特に有効です。計算終了を待たずに、ブラウザに瞬時にレスポンスを返せます。また、計算用のサーバーの負荷が高くなりすぎないように、同時に走る計算タスクの数を制限することができます。もし負荷が高くなるようなら、計算用サーバー（ワーカー）を増やして分散処理することも可能です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。手法を複数書いて頂き、本当に勉強になります。redisに興味があったため、3を試してみようと思います！質問の意図からはそれますが、Noguchiさんからして、今回のような構成（RoRとPythonを共存させる）はやめたほうが良いでしょうか？

RoRだけで実現することや、Pythonだけで実現することもできなくないため、参考までに伺いたいです。

仮に100万人、200万人のユーザーがついたときに今回のがボトルネックになることが懸念としております・・・。

Comment: もしこのプロジェクトがまだ黎明期で、実証実験のプロトタイプを作っているなら言語を統一した方が安く早く仕上がると思います。1Mユーザーに対応すなら、ピーク時の同時アクセス数にもよりますが、適材適所で疎結合の分散処理型の設計にするのが良いでしょう。

RoRのウェブフロントは適材適所だし、疎結合にすれば"高度な計算"のバックエンドをRで実装するとか、Hadoopクラスタで重たいバッチジョブを走らせるとか、いろいろ応用が利きます。計算種別毎にキューを作って、対応するバックエンドを追加すれば、既存のシステムにほとんど手を加えることなく新サービスがリリースできますね。